# How to automatically add appropriate class name to the React elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an objective to add the class names to the generated html elements. Class names must correspond to the react components classes. It is necessary for test purposes. I.e. when i declared `<SomeClassComponent/>` or created element with `React.createElement(SomeClassComponent)`  i expect to have `<div class="SomeClassComponent">` in the output.
How can I implement this without changing the React source code?

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan to do this without changing any code...

Comment: You're right. I mean, without changing the source code of React. For example using inheritance and overriding.

Comment: Oh... yeah that's pretty much a given. Glad you updated the question. I'll look into this after work.

Answer (score 0):

this.constructor.name should be the way to do this. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/53321/)

```
<div className={this.constructor.name}>
```

Comment: It is ok, but i need automatic class naming without rewriting existing code.